# Windows Explorer crashes on boot/open

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I have a laptop that is unable to open the Windows File Explorer, through the Windows File Explorer "app". Every time I open it, the whole Explorer crashes and resets.

However, if I run a simple command to find "c:", it launches with no issue.

Resetting it in Task manager does not fix it, I have shut down and restarted the machine with no effect, and I have even attempted a repair of the Windows 11 OS (only through the advanced boot menu).

Is there a way to fix this without re-installing the OS?

Comment: You have probably inadvertently installed a 3rd party shell extension that is causing this.  Check out [this app](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and try disabling everything.  Does it work then?  Add the extensions back one by one until you find your culprit.

Comment: Still on 10 here, but if you still have the option to choose opening to `This PC` or `Home/Quick Access`, does it fail in either mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this before. It is usually related to shell extensions, especially 32-bit shell extensions.

(1) Assuming your OS is 64-bit, look for heavy use of shell extension Apps (like WinMerge) and use the 64-bit version. If using Adobe, use the 64-bit version. Look at all your Apps, and update to 64-bit versions where possible.

I have here and have occasionally used Nirsoft Shellview and Shellview x64 but there are so many extensions, that was no too usefull. Converting Apps to 64-bit was more useful.

(2) When done, do a Windows 11 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download.

Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB Key.

Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.

Proceed normally answering the prompts.
The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.